# How to search for a value in a sub array and get to know the key index of that sub array

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, key-value, arrays

I have an array with this structure:

```
$months = array(
     MM => array(
         'start' => DD, 
         'end'   => DD,
         'type'  => (string),
         'amount'=> (float),
      ),
 );
```

MM is a month (01-12, string), DD a day in the month (01-31, string). 
Not all months may be in the array. For each month, there is a variable number of sub-arrays with ranges with unique days each. For example, a month has three sub arrays with three ranges of days, but the days used in these ranges will never overlap or duplicate, each DD value is unique. With the only exception that in some ranges 'start' and 'end' may coincide (same DD day), but there will never be two identical 'start' days or two identical 'end' days for each month.

I need to use this array while looping months and days within each month. While looping each day in the month, I need to check if that particular day has a match in 'start' or 'end'. If the match is true, I need also to retrieve adjacent values.

In doing this I have encountered one problem: how do I get to know the key index of the sub-array where there's such match? For example, how do I know if the match is on

```
$months['09'][3]['start'] == $current_day_in_loop;
```

or rather:

```
$months['09'][6]['start'] == $current_day_in_loop;
```

or yet another key?

Since I don't know how many ranges there are for each month, the index key is variable or there might not be any at all. How to find whether the matched value is on key `[3]` or `[6]`? Once I know the key I can use it to find adjacent values in the same sub-array.

Comment: I wonder where you want to use this structure

Comment: it's a sort of calendar and I need to store a variable number of ranges of days for each month - years are not taken into consideration; I might alter the structure of the array if there's a good reason to

Comment: well, you can achieve that easily with date() time() functions of php. Why there is an explicit need of this particular type of Structure? I mean why re-invent the wheel when its already there?

Comment: I don't need timestamps and I need to take years out of this data. It's unrelated with present time. Is there any php functions that would help me build date ranges? Furthermore later I need to use the same array data in a javascript object too.

Comment: date() converts any date-string or a timestamp in your own custom format. if you don't want years, its good to go. Building date ranges is possible. If you are getting values in php then it is easy to transfer it to a JS variable.

Comment: `$months['09'][3]['start']` does not match the structure of `$months` at the top

Answer (score 3):

You could perform a filter to determine which days matches:

```
$matches = array_filter($months['09'], function($item) use ($current_day_in_loop) {
    return $item['start'] == $current_day_in_loop;
});
// if $matches is empty, there were no matches, etc.
foreach ($matches as $index => $item) {
    // $months['09'][$index] is the item as well
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try with the below example for getting the key :

```
//loop start
    if (($key = array_search($searchedVal, $dataArr)) !== false) {
        echo $key;
    }
// loop end
```

Comment: That would work if each element of `$dataArr` is a scalar, but in this case it comprises arrays.

Answer (score 1):

> If the match is true, I need also to retrieve adjacent values. In doing this I have encountered one problem: how do I get to know the
> key index of the sub-array where there's such match? For example, how
> do I know if the match is on

If I understand correctly, the main issue you're having is you want to retrieve the next and previous elements of a match but don't know how because you don't know what the keys are.

You can achieve this by iterating through the array via **[`next`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.next.php)**

```
$months = array(
     '01' => array(
         'start' => '1', 
         'end'   => '31',
         'type'  => 'hello',
         'amount'=> 2.3,
      ),
     '02' => array(
         'start' => '2', 
         'end'   => '31',
         'type'  => 'best',
         'amount'=> 2.5,
      ),
     '03' => array(
         'start' => '3', 
         'end'   => '31',
         'type'  => 'test',
         'amount'=> 2.4,
      ),       
 );

$matches = array();
$prev = null;
$prev_key = null;
$key = key($months);
$month = reset($months);

while($month) {

    $next = next($months);
    $next_key = key($months);

    foreach(range(1,31) as $current_day_in_loop) {
        //if end or start match grab the current, previous and next values
        if($month['start'] == $current_day_in_loop
        || $month['end'] == $current_day_in_loop) {
            $matches[$key] = $month;

            if($prev)
                $matches[$prev_key] = $prev;
                
            if($next)
                $matches[$next_key] = $next;
        }
    }
    
    $prev = $month;
    $prev_key = $key;
    $month = $next;
    $key = $next_key;
}

print_r($matches);
```

Comment: that's correct, but unfortunately in my case I'm in a for loop iterating each month of the year regardless if there are $months or not; when I need to fetch ranges, I'm already looping days in a sub for loop, and "foreach" of these I can only check if there's a match. But thanks, it's useful.